# APA style in-text citations

Tags: apa

How would one differentiate between two different sources (websites) that both:

1. Have the same title
2. Have an unknown author
3. Do not list a publishing date/year

Answer (score 1):

The APA Manual says:

- If there is no author, you put the title in place of the author name. (Use "Anonymous" only, if the author is given as "Anonymous" in the publication! Use the nickname, if a pseudonymous nickname is given.) Alphabetize by the first significant word in the title (not by "The ..." or "A ...").
- If there is no publication date, write *n.d.* (in italics).
- If several works by the same author are published on the same date, add "a", "b" and so on to the publication date.

Taken together, I would say that your two sources could probably be listed as:

> Title of blog post. (*n.d.*a) http://www.url...
>
> Title of blog post. (*n.d.*b) http://www.otherurl...
>
> [Unfortunately this website does not italicize text if there is no whitespace. "*" signifies the beginning and end of italicized text.]

In text you would cite these as:

> bla bla bla (Title of blog post, *n.d.*a) bla bla bla

In effect "a" will point to one URL, "b" to another.

Note that in most cases you would not give the title of a website, but that of an individual article on a website. E.g. you would cite your question here not as `asfgas. (2015). Writers beta. http://writers.stackexchange.com`, but as `asfgas. (2015, May 18). APA style in-text citations. http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/17315/apa-style-in-text-citations`.  (Note that blog posts are cited with day and month, not only year.) Only if a website contains only one coherent work (e.g. a webcomic) would you cite this by the title of the whole website instead of by an individual post.